# Overwriting lazy loaded relationship query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

In my Symfony 4 Project, I've got a Model "Ticket" which has a `ManyToOne` relationship with the model "User" (with the name of "requester"):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User",cascade={"merge", "persist"})
 */
private $requester;
```

Now, in my controller, I request the first Ticket by doing

```
$ticket = $this->ticketRepository->find(1);
return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', compact('ticket'));
```

Now, in my twig template, I can do this:

```
<p>{{ ticket.requester.name }}</p>
```

and it will lazy-load the name of the requester.

This all works great, but I need to overwrite the method Doctrine uses internally to get this requester (`User`), but I can't find how to.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what sort of change would you make if you could override this method?  Changing the lazy load to eager load is easy enough.  Detecting when the user is loaded is also easy.  What else do you want to do?

Comment: The reason is because I want to cache the results.

Comment: I suppose you could look at the generated proxy entities and see how lazy loading is implemented.  It's messy to say the least.  Pretty sure that the normal Doctrine caching infrastructure is already being used so it's doubtful you will see any performance enhancements.  And if performance really is an issue then just eager load.  Lot faster then pretty much anything else.

Comment: @Cerad How can I test if the normal Doctrine caching infrastructure is actually used? If I enable my doctrine metadata/query/result cache driver, and check my profiler, I can actually see it doing the SQL query. Just to be clear: In practice I have a bunch of tickets on an index page, which queries the requesters, and some other related data. I see about 30 SQL queries per page load, which seems a bit much...

Comment: To be honest I don't know the inside details of the Doctrine cache.  The database itself does caching as well.  But if it the number of queries that alarm you then do eager loading.  Just write a repository method called maybe TicketRepository::findWithUser and then add both ticket and user to the select statement.  And all those individual user queries go away.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help @Cerad

Answer (score 0):

In the same Entity you probably have a getRequester method you can use that to implement your caching mechanism, if you don't have it create it, and use it in twig as simply as:

```
{{ticket.getRequester().name}}
```

Or you can simply use any of the available [Doctrine Caching Methods](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/caching.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ticket.requester` actually uses `ticket.getRequester()` internally. 
It doesn't seem fitting though that I need to handle the caching for User in the Ticket Entity. I was hoping there would be a method I could write in UserRepository (where I can use queryBuilder and `useResultCache`) that the lazy loading actually uses instead.